# Representing multivariate optimization problem as unconstrained single variable optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a function $f(x,y)$ that I must optimize (max and min) on G={$(x,y)|x+y=9$}

I am asked to represent the problem as an unconstrained single variate optimization problem.

I'm really not sure how to begins this. Can someone offers some hint?

Comment: It should read G={$(x,y) | x+y=9$}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Can you write $G$ as $G={(x,y(x))}$ for some $y(x)$? Then $f(x,y)$ becomes $f(x,y(x))$ or a new function of $x$, which we call $g(x)$.